# change jquery.animate depending on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

When `button.btn` is clicked, `div.img-box` will move with animation.
I'd like to change the animation depending on the place of `div.img-box`.
First I click the button, it moves collectly.
Second I click, the image whose `margin-right` is now 10px does not move. 
I have this code.

js

```
$(function(){
    var mr = parseInt($('.img-box').css('margin-right'), 10);
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        if (mr == 10) {
            $(".img-box").animate( { marginRight: '300px' }, 'slow' );
        } else {
            $(".img-box").animate( { marginRight: '10px' }, 'slow' );
        };
    });
});
```

html

```
<button class="btn"></button>
<div class="img-box"><img src="xxx.png"></div>
```

css

```
.img-box{
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 200px 25%;
}
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `var mr = parseInt($('.img-box').css('margin-right'), 10);` inside the `click()` function.

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        var mr = parseInt($('.img-box').css('margin-right'), 10);
        if (mr == 10) {
            $(".img-box").animate( { marginRight: '300px' }, 'slow' );
        } else {
            $(".img-box").animate( { marginRight: '10px' }, 'slow' );
        };
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/kc3h9mrt/)

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous function is called only once, so that "mr" is only calculated once, so that when the function to attached to your button is called, it's using a global variable that was set to  200. even after it moves, the mr variable is still 200, because you never updated the variable.

imtheman seems to have answered this as i was typing this out, but he's right, put the mr variable definition in the function so that it's calculated every time the button is clicked, rather than one time when the javascript is run.